# How do I add new buttons to an existing form?

Tags: drupal-6

I want to add new buttons to an existing form.

I want one button that, when clicked, saves the filled in values and reloads the same form.

The second button should save the filled in values and redirect to another form.

How do I add new buttons to the form and provide actions to take for each button?

Answer (score 0):

Is this a webform form, as in created by the Webform module?
If you are talking about a Webform, it sounds like you'll need to create a custom module to provide advanced additional processing. You used to be able to add some additional processing in Webform under the Advanced settings, but to manipulate the buttons the way your describing I assume you'll need to employ the hook_form_alter() function. This post outlines that method for someone with a similar problem: http://drupal.org/node/1050656#comment-4053130

In that module you'll need to point to a special submit handler with something like this

```
    function mymodule_form_alter(&$form, $form_state, $form_id) {
 //...     
if ( YOURCONDITIONS && in_array($form_id,array('webform-client-form-YOURFORMID'))) {
      $form['submit']['#submit'][] = 'mymodule_form_YOURSPECIALHANDLER';
     }
}
```